# Error "@LN_S@: command not found" when attempting to build BlueZ 5.66 from source

Tags: autoconf, bluez

I have downloaded BlueZ 5.66 source from http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.66.tar.xz onto an Ubuntu 22.04 system, and am attempting to build it from source. I have executed the following commands:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev autoconf python3-docutils
cd bluez-5.66
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental
```

This succeeds, and here's the output just in case it matters:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking how to create a pax tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict__
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether gcc accepts -fPIE... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fsanitize=address... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fsanitize=leak... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fsanitize=undefined... yes
./configure: line 5986: AC_DISABLE_STATIC: command not found
./configure: line 5987: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL: command not found
checking for explicit_bzero... yes
checking for getrandom... yes
checking for rawmemchr... yes
checking for signalfd... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for linux/types.h... yes
checking for linux/if_alg.h... yes
checking for linux/uinput.h... yes
checking for linux/uhid.h... yes
checking for sys/random.h... yes
checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.28... yes
checking for dbus-1 >= 1.6... yes
checking D-Bus configuration directory... /etc
checking D-Bus system bus services dir... /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services
checking D-Bus session bus services dir... /usr/share/dbus-1/services
${prefix}/share/zsh/site-functions
checking for libudev >= 172... yes
checking for udev_hwdb_new in -ludev... yes
checking udev directory... /lib/udev
checking for libical... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking systemd system unit dir... /lib/systemd/system
checking systemd user unit dir... /usr/lib/systemd/user
checking for rst2man... rst2man
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/bluetoothd.rst
config.status: creating lib/bluez.pc
config.status: creating mesh/bluetooth-meshd.rst
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

But then it fails when I run "make":

```
make -j 4
  GEN      lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h
/bin/bash: line 1: @LN_S@: command not found
  GEN      lib/bluetooth/hci.h
/bin/bash: line 1: @LN_S@: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:13176: lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:13176: lib/bluetooth/hci.h] Error 127
  GEN      lib/bluetooth/hci_lib.h
/bin/bash: line 1: @LN_S@: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:13176: lib/bluetooth/hci_lib.h] Error 127
  GEN      lib/bluetooth/sco.h
/bin/bash: line 1: @LN_S@: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:13176: lib/bluetooth/sco.h] Error 127
```

Am I missing some dependency?

(I would note that these instructions worked for me on earlier versions of BlueZ. Also [this page](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-bluez-latest-version-on-ubuntu/) implies these are the right instructions for Ubuntu 22.04))

After searching around more, I found [this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1551641) that has some helpful output about the missing AC_PROG_LIBTOOL macro. I ran

```
$ aclocal
$ autoconf
configure.ac:36: warning: The macro `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' is obsolete.
configure.ac:36: You should run autoupdate.
aclocal.m4:121: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:36: the top level
```

And then that gave me the hint to run `autoupdate`. Once I did that, the compile at least started in earnest. But then I got this error:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.7 Debian-2.4.7-4, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.6.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.7 Debian-2.4.7-4
libtool: and run autoconf again.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:7537: gdbus/mainloop.lo] Error 63
```

And now I'm not sure how to get past that error.

But in general, does this mean there's an error in BlueZ 5.66 in that it's using AC_PROG_LIBTOOL when it shouldn't be?